# Angular 2 pipe, using observable correctly, my pipe does not return a poster path

Tags: angular, pipe, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to call my service to get a poster Url for all my movies (Want to show the poster of them). I'm using Angular2 and have for now created a pipe that should do the job.

I have this code:

```html
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-4">
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let movie of MoviesOnNas">
        <span>{{movie.MovieYear}}</span>
        <img src="{{movie.MovieId | poster}}" class="thumbnail" alt="">
        {{movie.MovieTitle}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you see the **let movie of MoviesOnNas** , it will show all movies there is in the MoviesOnNas object.

In the line:

```html
<img src="{{movie.MovieId | poster}}" class="thumbnail" alt="">
```

I'm trying to use a custom pipe I have created. It looks like this.

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'poster' })
export class PosterPipe implements PipeTransform {

constructor(public movieService: MovieService) {

}

transform(value: string, args: string[]): any {
    if (value) {
        // Go call api to get poster.
        this.movieService.getMoviePoster(value).subscribe((data) => {
            console.log("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data);
            var poster = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + data;
            return poster;
        });
    }
    else {
        // Insert could not find movie poster.
        return "../../assets/img/poster.png";
    }
}
}
```

The pipe should return the poster url. The problem is that The code I have provided does not work. It won't load the url and show the picture. In the console.log, I can see that the url path is actually working if I use it in the browser.

If I do something like this:

```js
if (value) {

    return "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/bqLlWZJdhrS0knfEJRkquW7L8z2.jpg"
}
```

Then it shows the picture correctly. So the problem must be the observable subscribe?

Can any see what could be wrong here?

Comment: Your pipe doesn't return a string, that's the problem. It doesn't even return the observable (which you could resolve with an `AsyncPipe`).

Comment: Okay, will look into that for now.. thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Why do you want to use a pipe to make an API call for each element, when you have the URL on the movie object?

You are potentially doing thousands of http request by having that pipe. It's a bad design.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use the async pipe when dealing with async operations.
Remember to return a promise or an observable.

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'poster'
})
class PosterPipe {
  apiCall;
  constructor() {
    // simulate http call
    this.apiCall = Observable.create(observer => {
      observer.next("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/");
    });
  }

  transform(value: string) {
    if(value) {
      return this.apiCall.first();
    }

    return Observable.of("../../assets/img/poster.png");


  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <img src="{{MovieId | poster | async}}">
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
   MovieId:string;
   constructor() {
    this.MovieId = 'Exists'
   }
}
```

Working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0au3ZkuoaPSpyUXjNOgl?p=preview)